# Continuity of a function defined via integral

Tags: real-analysis

The statement below seems true to me, but I'd like to substantiate it with a reference to a theorem that supports it (or understand why it's false!)

Let $F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:

$$
F(x,t) = \int_\mathbb{R} A(x,y) B(y,t) \, dy
$$

and assume that the functions $A,B$ are such that $F(x,t)$ is well defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $A$ is continuous in the variable $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is continuous in the variable $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $F$ is continuous for any $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary true, you probably need some kind of uniformity to get it. We want $F(x + \Delta x, t) - F(x, t) = \int_{\mathbb R} (A(x + \Delta x, y) - A(x, y))B(y, t)\, dy = \int_{\mathbb R} o(1)B(y, t)\, dy$ be $o(1)$, but it doesn't have to be, because $o(1)$ under integral isn't uniform by $y$.

To get more precise example, let $B(y, t) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{y}, y > 1\\1\end{cases}$ (we will need integral of $B$ to diverge).

Choose $A(x, y)$ s.t.:

1. $A(x, y) = 1$ in rectangles $x \in [-\frac{1}{5n + 2}, -\frac{1}{5n + 3}], y \in [e^n, e^{n + 1}]$
2. $A(x, y) = 0$ outside of rectangles $x \in [-\frac{1}{5n + 1}, -\frac{1}{5n + 4}], y \in [e^n - 1, e^{n + 1} + 1]$
3. $0 \leq A(x, y) \leq 1$ everywhere.
   [[image: schematics of <span class=]$A$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7nBT.png)
   Not in scale - $A$ is equal to $1$ on red rectangles and $0$ outside of green rectangles. Red rectangles approaches vertical axis but don't intersect it, their heights grow rapidly, any vertical line intersects at most one green rectangle, and there are vertical lines arbitrarily close to $x = 0$ which intersect red rectangle.

Now, clearly $F$ is defined everywhere (as $A(x, y)B(y, t)$ is bounded and non-zero only on bounded region), and $F(0, 0) = 0$ (as $A(0, y) = 0$).

However, $F(-\frac{1}{5n + 2.5}, 0) > \int\limits_{e^n}^{e^{n + 1}} \frac{1}{y}\, dy = 1 \nrightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice counterexample. Indeed, I now think that a sufficient condition for my claim is the existence of a nonnegative function $g(y)$ such that:

1. $\int_\mathbb{R} g(y) dy < \infty$
2, If $\{ (x_n,t_n) \}$ is a sequence converging to $(x,t)$ as $n \to \infty$, then $|A(x_n,y)B(y,t_n)| \leq g(y)$ for all $(n, y) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Then the Dominated convergence theorem would imply continuity of F, I think

Comment: I think your condition with sequence is equal to just $\forall x, t: |A(x, y) B(y, t)| \leq g(y)$, because we can choose any $(x_1, t_1)$ and still get convergence to $(x, t)$. It's probably indeed enough - when we calculate $F(x + \Delta x, t + \Delta t) - F(x, t)$, integrals over finite part will converge, and integrals over the rest of the plane will be small.